# ReSharper search pattern: "Can not parse pattern"

Tags: structural-search, resharper-5.x

R# 5.1.1751.8

When I perform a pattern search for...

```
catch (Exception e) {}
```

...I'm shown an error dialog which says "Can not parse pattern".

What about that pattern cannot be parsed?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I emailed JetBrains support and got the following response:

ReSharper cannot parse only part of a C# language construct.  In this case, 'catch(Exception e){}' is part of a try/catch construct.  The following will search for empty catch clauses:

```
try {
    $stmt$
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

( where $stmt$ is "one or more statements" ).